# url-rewriting - set default web-site path

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I set a default path for files?

What i mean that if i have this address for exapmle:
`http://www.mysite.com/example/example2` for the file `example.php`.

And I have include function in example.php. lets say, `include('a.php');`

Its looking for http://www.mysite.com/example/example2/a.php.
I need it to look for http://www.mysite.com/a.php

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/example2/a.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
php_value include_path "/full/path/to/Document/Root:."
```

to set include path that will let you include file as `include('a.php');`